# Managing multiple upstream git submodule URL's in private repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am developing applications for my company where we use a private git repo inside our company's network. I am able to work with our git projects both internally and externally through the use of multiple upstreams to the same host (but through different SSH ports), like so:

```
external      ssh://user@externalhost.example.com:1234/var/git/project.git
origin        ssh://user@internalhost.example.com/var/git/project.git
```

My submodules work only when I connect internally. Here's an example submodule upstream:

```
[submodule "common-code"]
    path = common-code
    url = ssh://user@internalhost.example.com:/var/git/common-code.git
```

Is there a way to manage multiple upstreams for submodules so that I can work with them both internally and external to my company network?

Note: I've found some old posts about this on SO but they didn't really resolve the OP's answer or were vague about how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The URL for a submodule can be a relative URL.  This is only *potentially* helpful, as it is then relative to the *default* remote URL.  So for a single clone, it still points to a single URL (either the internal *or* the external, depending on which remote URL is the default); but you can create clones for internal use and separate clones for external use, and then using a relative URL for the submodule ought to work.

If for whatever reason you really need to use a single clone - perhaps you're working on a laptop and switch back and forth frequently enough that it would be inconvenient to share local changes between two clones - then the only option I can think of would be to create a script to modify the local configuration when you switch between internal and external.  Still I would think it best not to be tweaking the submodule paths, so I'd use a relative URL for that, and just modify the remote configuration as you move from internal to external or vice versa.

Comment: I think I prefer the idea of using one clone for internal and another clone for external use. But how would that work in practice? Wouldn't I then have to manage two sub-modules? Also, I would have to write my code to use two different paths depending on which network I am connected to?

Comment: @ToddHammer : Why would using multiple clones mean that you need multiple sub-modules?  And why would your code be aware of the location of the git clone?  I'm not sure how to more specifically address your questions, because it seems we are making very different assumptions about how things would be set up